# How to remove sharp spikes from Local Field Potential Data using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, noise, medical

Trying to work on this data that was recorded and there are some terrible sharp spikes present in the data. Not sure if it is a wire issue.

I already removed DC offsets, bandpassed filter 0.5-150Hz and notch filtered the powerline noise. I tried several filter types but I can not seem to find a solution for this ugly LFP.

Currently, I am segmenting out the data and concatenating the LFP once I remove the noisy data.

The image I attached is from one channel. The same noise occurs in every channel.

I have tried Median filter, moving average, harmonic or notch filters, wavelet decomposition, savitzky-golay filter.
A lot of these filters removed a lot of data or lost the wave shape of the data.
[Example of channel with noisy data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtiWz.jpg)

Comment: Please add a small sample of raw data to your question, and please add at least one solution that you have tried (median filtering for example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you please respond to my question? I like to know if my suggest solution is working.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the "clean data" is normally distributed, and that the spikes deviate by significant magnitude, we may apply the following stages:

- Compute median filter of the data (assume that median filtered result excludes the spikes).

  ```
   medA = medfilt1(A);
  ```
- Compute the absolute difference between the data and the median filtered data.
  The spikes in `absD` are going to be with large values compared to the normal data.

  ```
   absD = abs(A - medA);
  ```
- Define some threshold, that values in `absD` above it, considered to be spikes.
  We may define the threshold as `4*sigma` (4*STD) of `medA`.
  Note: The threshold may require some calibration for including the spikes and excluding the data.

  ```
   sigma = std(medA);
   thresh = 4*sigma;
  ```
- Mark spikes as elements where `absD > thresh`, and replace the "spikes" with values from `medA`:

  ```
   spikesA = absD > thresh;
   cleanA = A;
   cleanA(spikesA) = medA(spikesA);
  ```

---

Code sample (with random data):

```
% Create random input 
A = randn(1, 10000);

% Add some spikes.
A(100) = 5;
A(1000) = -7;
A(4000) = 6;
A(7000) = 15;

figure;plot(A);grid on;title('A');

medA = medfilt1(A);  % Apply median filter. In case there are few spikes next to each other, use medfilt1(A, 5) or medfilt1(A, 7)...
absD = abs(A - medA);  % Different of each element from it's median filtered value.

figure;plot(absD);grid on;title('absD');

sigma = std(medA);  % Compute standard deviation after median filtered (STD without the spikes)
thresh = 4*sigma;  % Define a threshold that above it data is considered a spikes - 4*sigma my need some calibration.

spikesA = absD > thresh;  % Logical array with true where difference from median is above thresh

cleanA = A;
cleanA(spikesA) = medA(spikesA);  % Replace the spikes with median filtered values.

figure;plot(cleanA);grid on;title('cleanA');
```

---

`A` (data with spikes):
[image]

`absD` (spikes have large values compared to the "normal data"):
[image]

`cleanA` (spikes replaced with values from `medA`):
[image]